# Sieve of Erathostenes ArrayIndexOutOfBounds

Tags: java, math, sieve-of-eratosthenes

trying to implement a simple sieve of erathosthenes to solve this question on project euler :

> The sum of the primes below 10 is 2 + 3 + 5 + 7 = 17.
>
> Find the sum of all the primes below two million.

[Link](http://projecteuler.net/problem=10)

My code keeps returning this error however :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   -2147479015   at Prime.main(Prime.java:28)

Can anyone give me any hints as to why? Here is the code:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Prime {
    /*
     * Input: an integer n > 1
     * 
     * Let A be an array of bool values, indexed by integers 2 to n, initially
     * all set to true.
     * 
     * for i = 2, 3, 4, ..., while i^2 ≤ n: if A[i] is true: for j = i^2, i^2 +
     * i, i^2 + 2i, ..., while j ≤ n: A[j] = false
     * 
     * Now all i such that A[i] is true are prime.
     */

        import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Prime {
    /*
     * Input: an integer n > 1
     * 
     * Let A be an array of bool values, indexed by integers 2 to n, initially
     * all set to true.
     * 
     * for i = 2, 3, 4, ..., while i^2 ≤ n: if A[i] is true: for j = i^2, i^2 +
     * i, i^2 + 2i, ..., while j ≤ n: A[j] = false
     * 
     * Now all i such that A[i] is true are prime.
     */

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean[] array = new boolean[2000000];
        BigInteger counter = new BigInteger("0");
        for (int value = 0; value < array.length; value++) {
            array[value] = true;
        }
        for (int i = 2; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i]) {
                int j = i * i;
                while (j > 0 && j < array.length) {
                    array[j] = false;
                    j += i;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 2; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i]) {
                counter = counter.add(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
            }
        }
        for (int value = 2; value < array.length; value++) {
            if(array[value]){
                System.out.println(value + ", ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\n" + counter);

    }

}
```

Comment: A gentle reminder, if you find an answer has helped you should mark it as accepted. The same with your other questions.

Comment: It's not the cause of your error, but for efficiency `i` only needs to be calculated where `i * i < array.length`. To debug your code, you might like to try to get it working for say, primes up to 100 before you increase that to 200000. Put some `println`s in to see what your values are.

Comment: Updated my code, the sieve is working, but the answer I get is incorrect, can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is coming from these lines:

```
        int j = i * i;
        while (j <= array.length) {
            array[j] = false;
            j += i;
        }
```

What's happening is that sometimes `i * i` is so big that it rounds the corner (overflows) and becomes negative.  Java does not have 'checked' integer math.  To fix this, you'll want to change your while condition to the following

`while(j > 0 && j < array.length)`

Also, your array is of size 200,000 and not 2,000,000.

Comment: Thank you for this, I have now fixed it, and the answer returned is  1997402614787, which it says is incorrect. Any ideas?

Comment: @SimonKiely I'd rather not solve the problem for you.  I think that goes against the spirit of ProjectEuler.  I promis that when you solve this yourself, you'll have benefitted much more than if I were to correct your code.  You're very close.

Comment: can you give me any hints? I am at a loss!:)

Comment: @SimonKiely I would start by dividing the problem.  Create the sieve first, then sum up the primes.  This way you can verify that your sieve is correct.  And then verify that your summation is working.  If both of these check out, check your edge cases.

Comment: @Simon Kiely, You also want to change `j += j` to `j += i`. This will mark multiples of `i` as composite numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Not to be snarky, but it's because you're going out of the bounds of the array. Your limit for `i` is the length of the array, and then `j` is equalling at a minimum the square of `i`. `j` is then being used as the location of the array to be accessed at line 28, which is out of bounds.